# Project keeps removing components

Tags: blazor

My project keeps placing my components in to ItemGroups in my project file and removing them.  I can delete these lines and it allows the component to work, but it's really frustrating that Visual Studio keeps doing this and I'd like to make control this behavior.

Here's an example of some of the code in my project file.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Remove="Pages\Publishers\PublishersList.razor" />
  <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="Pages\Components\PublisherForm.razor" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I just do this to get them to work.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <!--<Content Remove="Pages\Publishers\PublishersList.razor" />-->
  <!--<_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="Pages\Components\PublisherForm.razor" />-->
</ItemGroup>
```

I just comment them out because I don't know if maybe at some point these lines might be needed for some reason.  Can anyone help me understand why this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem :( 
Did you find the cause?

Comment: Still happening to me randomly!